# Docker compose Unable to connect

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've created docker-compose.yml file with the following content. My docker service runs ok, docker run hello-world works just fine and after running command

```
docker-compose build && docker-compose up -d
```

I see no errors but in the browser I'm getting an error Unable to connect when I go to localhost:8000

```
version: '3'

services:
  nginx:
    image: nginx:stable-alpine
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx/default.conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
    ports:
      - "8000:80"
    depends_on:
      - php
      - mysql   

  php:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: php
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html
    ports:
      - "9000:9000"

  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: mysql
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: 
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./mysql:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_DATABASE: db
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
```

When I run command

```
docker-compose exec php ls
```

I can see the list of files and folders

Comment: Run `docker logs nginx` and provide output, please.

Comment: @VolodyaLombrozo Thanks! I had a colon after listen directive in my conf. So silly mistake

Comment: Glad you found the bug